# Shell script to copy video files to another folder

Tags: file-system, bash, osx

I recently started running but hate running both in the quiet and with music, so i've been listening to podcasts.  Unfortunately, I've caught up with all my favorites and so I've started listening to some iTunesU courses, but unfortunately (again) very few of them have audio-only versions.

I wrote a shell script to copy any recently added iTunesU video files to another folder as m4a files (via ffmpeg) but since it's the first such script that i've ever written I am slightly worried to set it to run every morning ...

Anyway, I would appreciate some feedback from you expert types of what potential problems there might be with how I have it working now or suggestions of how I might improve part of it.  Also, as you'll see, I tried to set up a function to do the extension check but couldn't get it to work that way, is there a way to do that?

```
#!/bin/bash

oldIFS="$IFS" # allow for files/directories with spaces in the names
IFS=$'\n'

is_video_file () 
{
    ext=$1

    if ([ $ext = "m4v" ] || [ $ext = "mp4" ]); 
        then
            return 1
        else
            return 0
    fi  
} # couldn't get this to work right...

iTunesU_Source=~/Music/iTunes_U/
iTunesU_Destination=~/Music/iTunesU_audio/

cd $iTunesU_Source

for sub in */; do
    echo;
    echo $sub

    dest_sub=${iTunesU_Destination}/${sub}

    # create the sub folder if it doesn't exist
    does_not_exist=false
    [ -d $dest_sub ] || does_not_exist=true

    if $does_not_exist;
        then
            mkdir $dest_sub
    fi

    # get the modified times for the two subfolders
    source_sub_time=$(stat -f "%m" -t "%s" ${sub})
    dest_sub_time=$(stat -f "%m" -t "%s" ${dest_sub})

    if $does_not_exist || (( $source_sub_time > $dest_sub_time )); 
        then
            cd $sub

            for file in *; do
                filename=$(basename $file)
                extension="${filename##*.}"
                filename="${filename%.*}"

                dest_file=$dest_sub$filename".m4a"

#               if ! [[ -f $dest_file ]] && (is_video_file $extension = 1);
                if ! [[ -f $dest_file ]] && ([ $extension = "m4v" ] || [ $extension = "mp4" ]);
                    then

                    ffmpeg -i $file -vn -acodec copy $dest_file
            fi
            done; # each file in source sub_folder

            cd ..
    fi # source sub_folder is new or recently modified

done

IFS="$oldIFS"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Function

The command

```
is_video_file $extension = 1
```

just passes the arguments `$extension` , `=` and `1` to the function `is_video_file`.

To check if the return value of `is_video_file` is *1*, do the following:

```
is_video_file "$extension"

if [ $? = 1 ]; then ...
```

However, making a function return *1* usually indicates an error; the return value *0* indicates success.

If you swap *1* and *0* in the definition of `is_video_file`, you can use

```
if is_video_file "$extension"; then ...
```

#### Further problems

- Every time you do not know the value of a variable with certainty, you should surround it with double quotes.

  Most of your variables are unquoted, while the strings are quoted. The latter is unnecessary.

  For example, you wrote

  ```
  [ $ext = "m4v" ]
  ```

  which might fail if `$ext` contains unanticipated characters.

  The commands

  ```
  [ "$ext" = "m4v" ]
  ```

  and

  ```
  [ "$ext" = m4v ]
  ```

  will both work fine.

#### Suggestions

- There is not need to restore the IFS and the end of the script. Modifying the IFS will only affect the script itself.
- Setting `IFS=$'\n'` gives a false sense of security. It's *still* necessary to quote all variables if their values are unknown.

Comment: Beware that the OP is on OS X, so `stat`'s `-f` and `-t` options have arguments.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. The OP didn't mention OS X anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It is so weird to quote variables but not strings... Also, the function based verification works now.

Answer (score 1):

- There is no need for the parentheses in the first `if` statement.
- You only need a semicolon at the end of an `if` statement if you put the `then` on the same line.
- `then` and `else` belong on the same indentation as `if`.
- Functions return the exit code of the last statement.
- As @Dennis mentioned, return code 0 is "true" and you should always quote variables.

So instead of

```
    if ([ $ext = "m4v" ] || [ $ext = "mp4" ]); 
        then
            return 1
        else
            return 0
    fi
```

you can write simply

```
    [ "$ext" = "m4v" ] || [ "$ext" = "mp4" ]
```

To avoid nasty problems with strange filenames you should use `./` before any glob starting with `*`, as in `for file in ./*`.

You don't need a semicolon after `done` - It's only ever needed if you want to add another command on *the same line* or (of course) if the semicolon is an actual parameter to the command, as in `find . -exec grep foo {} \;`